# How to block or redirect an auto reply?

Tags: vba, outlook

My macro is sending mails to some list of recipients from some mailbox. Some recipients will send an auto-reply.

I want to block the auto-reply option. Auto-replying to a different mailbox would also be fine for me.

```
Sub SendEmail(  what_address As String, _
                subject_line As String, _
                mailbox_name As String, _
                mail_body As String )

    Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim olMail As Outlook.MailItem

    Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set olMail = olApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)

    olMail.To = what_address
    olMail.Subject = subject_line
    olMail.SentOnBehalfOfName = mailbox_name
    olMail.BodyFormat = olFormatHTML
    olMail.HTMLBody = mail_body
    olMail.Send
End Sub
```

Comment: You should add a bit more verbiage to your question. As it stands makes very little to no sense.

Comment: you cannot control if the email is sent a reply by another mail client.

Comment: Thank you Sorceri, can I force him maybe to auto-reply on another address provided?

Comment: Hi Paul Francis, thank you for looking at this. My macro is sending mails to some list of recipients from some mailbox. Some recipients will send auto-reply which I don't want as it's doing a mess for me. Therefore I wanted to block auto-reply option. Replying on different mailbox would also be fine for me

Comment: There is no difference between auto reply and a reply created by a human. You can use MailItem.ReplyRecipients collection to direct replies to a different mailbox, but that will affect replies created by the recipient as well.

Comment: Hi Dmitry, the workaround you provided works with Direct reply only for me, not with auto-reply

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Outlook object model doesn't provide anything for that. Moreover, you are talking about a client's feature which can't be managed or set up in the email.

The only property which you can set is the [ReplyRecipients](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff862985(v=office.15).aspx) , returns a Recipients collection that represents all the reply recipient objects for the Outlook item.